# How to select query using list and between

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table to keep range of our troubleshooting tickets numbers monthly. Due to I store monthly tickets detail in separate tables How do I get ticket range records that my list ticket numbers are between of them? Sure I can use by PHP, but I have to do it by mysql query.

My sample table and data is as below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `ticket_range` (
  `id`          int(11)              NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_range` bigint(20)  unsigned NOT NULL,
  `end_range`   bigint(20)  unsigned NOT NULL,
  `range_year`  smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `range_month` tinyint(3)  unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ticket_range` 
(`id`, `start_range`, `end_range`, `range_year`, `range_month`) VALUES
( 1  ,          1   ,    522039  ,    2019     ,     1        ),
( 2  ,     522040   ,   1161530  ,    2019     ,     2        ),
( 3  ,    1161531   ,   1754174  ,    2019     ,     3        ),
( 4  ,    1754175   ,   2359084  ,    2019     ,     4        );
```

I expected query was as below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ticket_range` WHERE (1700000,1200000,500000) BETWEEN `start_range` AND `end_range`
```

To give me result like below:

```
id | start_range | end_range | range_year | range_month | ticket
---+-------------+-----------+------------+-------------+---------
 4 |   1754175   |  2359084  |    2019    |      3      | 1700000
 4 |   1754175   |  2359084  |    2019    |      3      | 1200000
 2 |    522040   |  1161530  |    2019    |      1      |  500000
```

Comment: Where does `ticket` value come from? Is there another table?

Comment: That is title for the ticket numbers as I mentioned in the query. It mean I need to show that ticket number in result too.

Comment: I don't get your results. 1700000 is not between 1754175 and 2359084, nor is 1200000. And 500000 is not between 522040 and 1161530.

Comment: I am so sorry that I paste the wrong result. I mean below result:

3 | 1161531 | 1754174 | 2019 | 3 | 1700000
3 | 1161531 | 1754174 | 2019 | 3 | 1200000
1 | 1       | 522039  | 2019 | 1 | 500000

Answer (score 0):

Check this your where condition is wrong.There should be one operand in the bracket not 3 values.
So try below query ,I have tested it-

```
SELECT id, 
       start_range, 
       end_range, 
       range_year, 
       range_month, 
       1700000 AS ticket 
FROM   `ticket_range` 
WHERE  1700000 BETWEEN `start_range` AND `end_range` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       start_range, 
       end_range, 
       range_year, 
       range_month, 
       1200000 
FROM   `ticket_range` 
WHERE  1200000 BETWEEN `start_range` AND `end_range` 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, 
       start_range, 
       end_range, 
       range_year, 
       range_month, 
       500000 
FROM   `ticket_range` 
WHERE  500000 BETWEEN `start_range` AND `end_range`
```

Comment: Thank you @Kedar. But the ticket list is dynamic and I get them form another table records. The list may be increase or decrease and I have to do it by mysql query.